# ActionMailer not sending, nothing in log

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to set up a simple contact form, which oddly enough is probably the only qualm i have so far with rails, its turned out to be a lot harder than it should be.

my mailer has `mail(to: "xxxxxx@gmail.com", subject: "Test")`, I am receiving no errors and I am not receiving any emails.

I changed `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false` to `true` yet I still have no errors or any information to go by in my log.

Except `Rendered contact_mailer/send_mail.html.haml (3.9ms)` then the page redirects as intended.

Comment: Have you checked the logs in the log/ directory?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, the development log. No errors, just tells me it rendered the mailer

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the root of the problem,

This call to the mailer just creates the object but does not actually deliver it:

`ContactMailer.send_mail(set_params)`

Adding deliver fixed the issue!

`ContactMailer.send_mail(set_params).deliver`